# Список переполнен?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу поместить в список все значения `<image:title>` вот отсюда: https://www.12amrun.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=10095501830&to=4172606832725

Это карта интернет-магазина. Ссылок там довольно-таки много. Мне необходимо получить все значения тегов `<image:title>`. Использую **bs4**.

```
# Поиск всех <image:title>
imgTitleList = soup.find_all('image:title')
print(imgTitleList)
# Вывод: []
```

Правильно я понимаю, что список пустой по причине его переполнения?
Если использовать `soup.find` (поиск первого элемента), то список пополняется содержанием первого найденного тега.

Отсюда вытекает следующий вопрос: для перебора такого объема данных что эффективнее будет использовать: список или кортеж?

Comment: Список пустой по причине отсутствия элементов, удовлетворяющих условиям поиска.

Comment: Что ж, это действительно похоже на то, что вы говорите. Но тогда по какой причине find_all не находит элементы?

Comment: Может быть, неправильно задано условие поиска?

Comment: то есть, вы хотите сказать, что там отсутствуют теги <image:title>?

Comment: Вам это проще выяснить.

Comment: Список не может быть переполнен.

Comment: `imgTitleList = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('image:title')]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url =  "https://www.12amrun.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=10095501830&to=4172606832725"
xml = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(xml.text)
# Поиск всех <image:title>
imgTitleList = soup.find_all('image:title')
print(imgTitleList)
```

Comment: Как этот код отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @insolor, этот код показывает, что список не пустой ;)